# Integral of Gibbs distribution?

Tags: integration

I would like to solve (or approximate) the following integral:
$$
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{\beta r_i}}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}e^{\beta r_k}} d\beta
$$
I know that $r_i$ in the numerator is not the largest of the r's, i.e., $r_i < \max\{r_1,r_2, ... , r_n \}$
I was able to find an exact closed-form solution for $n=2$, but I am wondering if it is possible to integrate for $n>2$. If not, would there be a way to find a reasonable approximation?

Comment: When the $r_i$ are integers, this is a rational function of $u=e^-\beta$ and therefore can be integrated via partial fractions.

Answer (score 1):

Its convergence depends on what $r_i$ you select. As

$$
\infty = \int_{0}^{\infty} 1d\beta = \int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-r_1\beta}+e^{-r_2\beta}+\cdots+e^{-r_n\beta}}{e^{-r_1\beta}+e^{-r_2\beta}+\cdots+e^{-r_n\beta}}d\beta
$$
At least one of the $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-r_i\beta}}{e^{-r_1\beta}+e^{-r_2\beta}+\cdots+e^{-r_n\beta}}d\beta$ should diverge.

Comment: Many thanks Ryoungwoo, for your prompt reply. Of course, you are rightl; I apologize, I was careless in my simplification of the problem. I know a priori that $r_i$ in the numerator is not the maximum of all the $r_i$. In this sense, I guess the title of this post (Gibbs distribution) is a misnomer.